# Address of a reference to first item of an array

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused about this:

I thought that if a pointer points to some object, assigning a dereference to some reference variable was a mere aliasing.

Example:

```
Object * p = &o;
Object & r = *p;
// r and o are the same object
```

I was aware there was some illegal cases, like:

```
Object * p = NULL;
Object & r = *p; // illegal
```

Now, what about the code below ?

```
const char * p = "some string";
const char & r = *p;
```

or

```
const char & r = *"some string";
```

I was said that this particular case involved temporary objects and, therefore I could'nt get the address of r and be sure it will point to a memory array containing my initial string.

What does C++ standard states about that case ? Is it another illegal case like the NULL provision, or is it allowed behavior.

In other words, is it legal or illegal (undefined behavior ?) to write something like ?

```
   char buffer[100];
   strcpy(buffer, &r);
```

Comment: Are you referring to what I said about temporaries [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122517/casting-c-string-to-unsigned-char-pointer/8122581#8122581)? That happened because the reference was to a different type (`unsigned char` rather than `char`), and so a temporary of the correct type had to be created. In this case, you will get a reference to the first character in the string literal since the types match.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the case you pointed out is clear, as variables are of different type (even if I guess most compilers won't care and do it the same way, but that's not the point). But it made me think of that one and that I was not really as sure as I thought of the behavior when dereferencing to an array item, then going back to the array from the address of the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**That's fine.**

The string literal's data buffer will exist for the duration of your program (usually in a special segment of the process memory).

> `[C++11: 2.14.5/8]:` Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string
>   literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. **A narrow
>   string literal** has type “array of *n* const char`”, where *n* is the size
>   of the string as defined below, and **has static storage duration** (3.7).
>
> `[C++11: 3.7.1/1]:` All variables which do not have dynamic storage
>   duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have
>   *static storage duration*. **The storage for these entities shall last for
>   the duration of the program** (3.6.2, 3.6.3).

After all, that's how keeping a pointer to it works! Recall that pointers don't magically extend object lifetime any more than do references.

Comment: (Any more than do references to non-`const`, that is.)

Comment: Although it should probably be mentioned that `r` is a reference to the first character, not to the entire string.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The type says that :D