# Is C++ at the same level of C?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm familiar with these two languages but don't write in them.

From the context of Microsoft specific versions of these languages and from what I understand, (Visual) C++ is basically C but object oriented.  Is that correct?

Is C and C++ on the same level?  Meaning, C++ does not sit on top of C?

I've often heard if you want to write an operating system (Windows) use C (but MS does not have a Visual C).  Can the same be said for C++?  Why or why not?

Comment: C With Classes died out a long time ago. C++ is C++. It's not C With Anything.

Comment: C++ is mostly a superset of C, but it does not "sit on top of" C. There's no formal definition of language levels so your question can't really be answered. Some such as Linus Torvalds think that C++ is inappropriate for OS work but others disagree.

Comment: AFAIK - Simply put, C++ is basically a superset of C (as opposed to a subset). I write and compile c code with a c++ compiler daily. As for why C, rather than C++ for an OS? Windows was written a million years ago in C, recent additions to it have all more-or-less been c++ or .net. Take GDI+ or the WMF classes. Even the taskbar has a c++ interface. And yes, you can do an OS with c++. See here for a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_operating_system

Comment: @enhzflep "I write and compile c code with a c++ compiler daily". Well, I hope you don't have any variable nammed `new` or `delete` then :P

Comment: @Xaqq - god no! That would be dumber than dumb. Never mind the fact that neither name constitutes a well-named variable - they're not in the least bit descriptive of their use.

Comment: @enhzflep: If C++ is a superset of C, doesn't that mean C++ sits on top of C?  Is it safe to say C++ would not be around if it weren't for C?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I think Linus would say that C++ is inappropriate for *any* work.

Comment: @4thSpace We couldn't know. Would Java be the same if C++ didn't exist (I'm saying that because their syntax are pretty close)?

Comment: C++ is NOT a superset of C.  It once was, but that was years ago.

Comment: @ascheplet - oh yes? Could you explain the mechanism by which this occured? I've seen additions over the years, but never a fundamental change, so I don't understand your assertion. Care to elaborate? In just the same way that the instructions of the i7 are a superset of the 8088 or 8086??

Comment: read the C++ creator page. http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#difference

Comment: @enhzflep: I like the 8088/8086 comparison.  That's clear.  Is that basically how it is with C and C++?  Meaning, now matter how far you dig into C++, you aren't going to find C?

Comment: @4thSpace - :) I consider the comparison the same in that the 8086 has the same add instruction, and the same registers AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, BP, SP, IP, CS, DS, ES and SS. The i7 has all of these and so, so many more. If it ran on the 8086 it will more-or-less run on the i7, naturally the same isn't true in reverse. In much the same way, you can declare `int i;` in either C or C++, you can use a `struct` in both C and C++, but in C++ you have the added weapon of a `class`, to name but a few instances of the subset/superset relationship they share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a big question... The short version is that there isnt really anything that can be done in C that cant be done in C++. A longer version can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879636/what-can-be-done-in-c-but-not-c).