# Is associativity and precedence of Operators different in C and C++? If so, Why?

Tags: c++, c, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

Recently I've come across this code, Which I assumed to understand and didn't bother to run, My answer (that i assumed in my head) was confirmed by the book **Let Us C**. Later when I try to give it a run in C, to my surprise the output was completely contrasting. *C++ is giving the output which I expected.*

C++ :

```
int a=1;
cout<<a<<a++<<++a;
```

Output :

```
113
```

C :

```
int a=1;
printf("\n%d %d %d",a,a++,++a);
```

Output:

```
3 2 3
```

I expected this to be the same as the output produced by C++.

*I don't have a very clear understanding of Precedence and Associativity of Operator. But this output seems to be out of blue.*

I'm using **Atom** as an editor and **C / C++ compiler GCC**.

Comment: KamilCuk But my question is Why these two programming languages are behaving differently?

Comment: `two programming languages` C __is not__ C++. These are _separate_ programming languages. `are behaving` Those constructs are undefined behavior. Both compilers should spawn demons. (and in late C++, it's valid, because the behavior was changed from undefined to unspecified).

Comment: In C, this is just undefined behavior. In C++, this may be legal. So you should remove all the stuff about C, and just ask if this is legal in C++. As for why they behave differently, it's because they are different languages with different rules.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. That means in each case the result is unpredictable so it's a moot point to try and explain why they are different.

Comment: And the fact that C++ is superset of C should be ignored?

Comment: Yes it should be ignored. They are different languages and that is how you should treat them.

Comment: It's not strictly a superset of C.  It's a C derived language, but it's not C.  Writing legal code that compiles and runs correctly in both languages is not trivial.  What you are doing, exploits undefined behavior.

Comment: "how do I know when it is undefined and when It's not?".  Read the language specs.  Search for C standard and C++ standard, chose the appropriate year(s) for your compilers and read them thoroughly.

Comment: This is not an issue between C and C++. A short example shows this is in 1 compilation unit in C++: https://godbolt.org/z/HTLM2Y

Comment: So that an expression is evaluated in a predictable manner, in C++17 the order-of-evaluation rules have been improved: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Re "*And the fact that C++ is superset of C should be ignored?*", C++ isn't a superset of C.

Comment: C++ is not a superset of C. C has variable-length arrays. C++ does not. That's not the only feature that C has and C++ doesn't. Here is an incomplete list with C features that are not in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879636/what-can-be-done-in-c-but-not-c Some of them will be implemented in C++20